# Fatal error: Cannot declare class JSMin, because the name is already in use in opencart 3.0.3.7

Tags: php, opencart-3

How can I fix the mistake on piece of code, I couldn't find explain about how I will fix it, ıf someone had been having such a problem like me, ı wait to your helping me

```
 class JSMin {
  const ORD_LF            = 10;
  const ORD_SPACE         = 32;
  const ACTION_KEEP_A     = 1;
  const ACTION_DELETE_A   = 2;
  const ACTION_DELETE_A_B = 3;

  protected $a           = '';
  protected $b           = '';
  protected $input       = '';
  protected $inputIndex  = 0;
  protected $inputLength = 0;
  protected $lookAhead   = null;
  protected $output      = '';

  // -- Public Static Methods --------------------------------------------------

  /**
   * Minify Javascript
   *
   * @uses __construct()
   * @uses min()
   * @param string $js Javascript to be minified
   * @return string
   */
  public static function minify($js) {
    $jsmin = new JSMin($js);
    return $jsmin->min();
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. I can't see the problem caused in the code presented: How do you use that snippet? Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

A couple notes here:

1. I don't use open cart, so I don't know how you are calling this class
2. It appears like you are attempting to use the archived git repo `rgrove/jsmin-php`, located here https://github.com/rgrove/jsmin-php

> The author has archived it and is urging not to use it anymore with suggestions to use other, better solutions.

**POSSIBILITY ONE**

If you are going to keep using it, however, you could modify it with a namespace like below—assuming opencart really has already declared it in it's native code:

```
<?php
namespace DeprecatedDontUse;

class JSMin
{
  const ORD_LF            = 10;
  const ORD_SPACE         = 32;
  const ACTION_KEEP_A     = 1;
  const ACTION_DELETE_A   = 2;
  const ACTION_DELETE_A_B = 3;

  protected $a           = '';
  protected $b           = '';
  protected $input       = '';
  protected $inputIndex  = 0;
  protected $inputLength = 0;
  protected $lookAhead   = null;
  protected $output      = '';
  ....etc
```

Then when you go to use it, you would do:

```
<?php echo \DeprecatedDontUse\JSMin::minify($JSstring) ?>
```

That should take care of a duplicate class naming issue.

---

**POSSIBILITY TWO**

If you are not autoloading this class somehow into your application and instead manually including it in a file, you will then just leave the script as is (no namespace), and instead of using `require('/path/to/jsmin.php');` or `include('/path/to/jsmin.php');` (whichever you used), you would use the `once` version of those, so `include_once('/path/to/jsmin.php');` or `require_once('/path/to/jsmin.php');`.

This is in case opencart is loading whatever script you are adding this into multiple times throughout the execution. It would only load the class once and not give you this error.